# Listing paths of all files with extension on a webpage

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there a command or way in python requests library to download all files with a specific extension from a web page? Or in the very least list them with full paths like the nest command in the ftp library? This is the page: https://gimms.gsfc.nasa.gov/SMOS/jbolten/FAS/L03/ and I want all files with extension .grib

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
data_html = soup(r'https://gimms.gsfc.nasa.gov/SMOS/jbolten/FAS/L03/', 'lxml')  # making soap
links = data_html.findAll(href=re.compile("/.grib$"))
```

However links has no entry

Answer (score 1):

Web servers work using the HTTP protocol which has no "list all files" method. Unless the server itself generates a list and sends for you to parse, there is no generic way to get a list of the files.

What you can do is download some html page, then parse it using a html parser like `lxml.html` and extract all links from that page. Then you send a request for each of those links.